# HttpListener Request Queue Timeout on Linux

Tags: linux, http, .net-core

I have the following application

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var listener = new HttpListener();
                listener.TimeoutManager.RequestQueue = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

The output of the application is as follows

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.HttpListenerTimeoutManager.set_RequestQueue(TimeSpan value)
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\a\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 13
Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.HttpListenerTimeoutManager.set_RequestQueue(TimeSpan value)
   at ConsoleApp2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\a\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\Program.cs:line 13
```

This was run on Debian but we get the same error on Alpine. No such error on Windows.

Is this truly not supported? If not, is it something that is managed within the OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is, if you want to run on Linux, don't use HttpListener. It's built on top of [HTTP.sys which is a Windows specific kernel mode listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-3.1)

There is an [ongoing discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/issues/88) related to deprecating HttpListener and it points to using Kestrel as an alternative